# How can I find the matching parts of string in each line of a loop of a Linux file then add this matching value to a variable?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ubuntu

```
    for line in $script
    do
    username=grep ‘^\[a-z\]\[^:\]*:’ $line
    dir=grep ‘:(/\[^:\]*):/\[^:\]\*$’ $line

    echo "line 1:" $username $dir
    done
```

So basically I have a file "script"
I want to loop through each line
then for each line I want to output only parts of the line which matches the regex condition into a variable.
There's supposed to be 2 variables which are different parts of the particular line of the file.
Then print these 2 variable

I tried the above code as well as some minor changes here and there but none of it works. Since the grep in Linux is supposed to be for a file thus I cannot grep through just a line

I even tried to create a "linefile" specifically so I can grep regex as seen below but still doesn't work

```
    for line in $script
    do
    touch linefile
    echo $line >> linefile
    username=grep ‘^\[a-z\]\[^:\]*:’ $linefile
    dir=grep ‘:(/\[^:\]*):/\[^:\]\*$’ $linefile
    rm linefile
    echo "line 1:" $username $dir
    done
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of the input and the expected output?

Comment: Fix any syntax errors flagged by pasting your code into https://shellcheck.net. Inlclude ~#!/bin/bash` as the first line. Update your question with those fixes. Good luck.

Comment: Try to understand the difference between a *file* and a *variable*. When you issue `touch linefile`, you create an empty *file* called `linefile` and you can run commands on this file as in `grep '^[a-z]*:' linefile` without prefixing it with a `$` sign. When you execute `username=$(grep '^[a-z]*:' linefile)`, you create a *variable* called `username` that you invoke with a `$` as prefix, like in `echo "User name is: $username"`.

Comment: Let us insist on a practice at stackoverflow: include a sample of your input and tell us what you expect. By the way, the regular expressions you are referring to are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `echo "$line" | grep '^\[a-z\]\[^:\]*:'`. Based on [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163810/grep-on-a-variable).

Also, I'm not sure what you trying to find with second regexp, but is seems that this won't find anything obvious. Maybe it'll be easier to use ERE (`grep -E`) instead of BRE?